# Halting Django's dev server via page request?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking at writing a portable, light-weight Python app.  As the "GUI toolkit" I'm most familiar with — by a wide margin! — is HTML/CSS/JS, I thought to use Django as a framework for the project, using its built-in "development server" (`manage.py runserver`).

I've been banging on a proof-of-concept for a couple hours and the only real problem I've encountered so far is shutting down the server once the user has finished using the app.  Ideally, I'd like there to be a link on the app's pages which shuts down the server and closes the page, but nothing I see in the Django docs suggests this is possible.

Can this be done?  For that matter, is this a reasonable approach for writing a small, portable GUI tool?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One *brute force* approach would be to let the process kill itself, like:

```
# somewhere in a views.py

def shutdown(request):
    import os
    os.kill(os.getpid(), 9)
```

Note: [`os.kill`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.kill) is only available on Unix (Windows alternative may be something like this: http://metazin.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/how-to-kill-a-process-in-windows-using-python/)

Comment: Unfortunately, I need to support Windows users, as well.  :-)

Comment: http://metazin.wordpress.com/2008/08/09/how-to-kill-a-process-in-windows-using-python/

Comment: Hey, that just might work.  I'll leave the question open for a bit to see if I can catch a more subtle, Django-friendly method than "shoot it in the face", but it does seem to get the job done.  ;-)

Comment: ... 9? You don't think that `atexit` handlers should get called?

Comment: Yes, they should. But by default, there are no `atexit` handlers registered in django. Anything I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the source code for `python manage.py runserver`:

http://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py

When you hit `Ctrl+C`, all it does is call `sys.exit(0)`, so you could probably just do the same.

Edit: Based on your comment, it seems Django is catching `SystemExit` when it calls your view function.  Did you try calling `sys.exit` in another thread?

```
import threading
thread = threading.Thread(target=sys.exit, args=(0,))
thread.start()
```

Edit: Nevermind, sys.exit from another thread only terminates that thread, which is not well documented in the Python docs. =(

Comment: That was my first thought, but Django catches the `SystemExit` exception and returns it as a page!  :-D

Answer (score 0):

It is works for me on Windows:

```
def shutdown(request):
    import os
    os._exit(0)
```